# Cant get angular bootstrap datepicker to init with right date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-formly

I am trying to modify the angular-formly UI datepicker in a project I got handed to me. The issue is this: 
There are two datepickers. When you click a radiobutton it shows the datepickers at which point I load the input fields using $scope.model.from & $scope.model.to. 
'from' is set to todays date and 'to' is set to six months ahead. Everything looks good this far, but if you click on the 'to'-picker the datepicker pops up and it shows todays date grayed out. If you flip to six months ahead you can see that date is blue (picked). If you close it and click it again it goes to the blue (and correct) date. 
The 'from'-picker shows todays date in blue, which is fine.
This is of course confusing and not optimal. I think the datepicker has to get refreshed, but I am not sure how. If I can get init date to work maybe I can pass the date from the 'from'-picker + 6 months to it. Im thinking that might make it work.

Im using Angular 1.6.9, angular-bootstrap 0.13.4, angular formly 7.0.1, angular-formly-templates-bootstrap 6.0.0

This is the relevant code:

this is the datepickerTpl.html

```
<p class="input-group">
<input type="text"
       id="{{::id}}"
       name="{{::id}}"
       ng-model="model[options.key]"
       class="form-control"
       ng-click="datepicker.open($event)"
       required
       is-open="datepicker.opened"
       init-date="dateOptions.initDate"
       datepicker-options="dateOptions" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="datepicker.open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

this is the CustomFormTypes.js

```
    /*@ngInject*/
function register(formlyConfig, formlyValidationMessages, $filter, gettext, adService) {
    function getDatepickerNgattrs() {
        var attributes = [
            'show-weeks',
            'starting-day',
            'min-mode',
            'max-mode',
            'init-date',
            'format-day',
            'format-month',
            'format-year',
            'format-day-header',
            'format-day-title',
            'format-month-title',
            'year-range',
            'shortcut-propagation',
            'datepicker-popup',
            'show-button-bar',
            'current-text',
            'clear-text',
            'close-text',
            'close-on-date-selection',
            'datepicker-append-to-body'
        ];

        var bindings = [
            'datepicker-mode',
            'min-date',
            'max-date'
        ];

        var statement = [
            'date-disabled',
            'custom-class'
        ];

        var ngModelAttrs = {};

        angular.forEach(attributes, function (attr) {
            ngModelAttrs[_.camelCase(attr)] = {
                attribute: attr
            };
        });
```

and further down:

```
{
        name: 'datepicker',
        templateUrl: 'shared/formService/datepickerTpl.html',
        wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError'],
        defaultOptions: {
            ngModelAttrs: getDatepickerNgattrs(),
            templateOptions: {
                showWeeks: true,
                closeText: 'close',
                currentText: 'today',
                clearText: 'clear',
                datepickerPopup: 'dd MMMM yyyy'
            }
        },
        controller: /*@ngInject*/ function ($scope) {

            $scope.dateOptions = {
                initDate: new Date('2015-06-22')
            };

            $scope.datepicker = {
                opened: false
            };

            $scope.datepicker.open = function () {
                $scope.datepicker.opened = true;
            };

            }
        }
```

this is the relevant part of the forms.service.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('forms')
    .factory('forms', forms);

    function getThisForm($scope, $rootScope) {
        var specific = [{
            className: 'row',
            fieldGroup: [{
                className: 'col-md-12',
                key: 'something-radiobuttons',
                type: 'radio',
                templateOptions: {
                    label: 'something something radiobuttons',
                    options: [{
                        name: 'radioOne',
                        value: 'radioOne'
                    }, {
                        name: 'radioTwo',
                        value: 'radioTwo'
                    }, {
                        name: 'radioThree',
                        value: 'radioThree'
                    }, {
                        name: 'radioFour',
                        value: 'radioFour'
                    }, {
                        name: 'radioFive',
                        value: 'radioFive'
                    }],
                    required: true,
                    onChange: function (v, o, s) 

                        if (s.model.from === undefined) {                           
                            s.model.from = new Date();

                            var tmpDate = new Date();
                            var tmpDate = new Date(tmpDate.setMonth(tmpDate.getMonth() + 6));                                
                            s.model.to = tmpDate;
                        } 

                        if (v !== 'radioThree') {
                            delete s.model['radioTwoInputBox1'];
                            delete s.model['radioTwoInputBox2'];
                        }

                        if (v === 'radioFive') {
                            delete s.model['radioFourInputBox'];
                        }
                        else {
                            delete s.model['OtherInputBox'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                className: 'col-md-3',
                type: 'datepicker',
                key: 'from',
                hideExpression: '!model["something-radiobuttons"]',
                templateOptions : {
                    label : 'from',
                    required: true,
                    datepickerOptions: {
                        format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                    }
                    ,
                    onChange: function (v, o, s) {
                        var fromDate = new Date(s.model.from);
                        fromDate.setMonth(fromDate.getMonth() + 6); 
                        s.model.to = fromDate;
                    }
                }
            }, {
                className: 'col-md-3',
                type: 'datepicker',
                optionsTypes: ['matchField'],
                key: 'to',
                hideExpression: function (v, o, s) {
                    return (s.model["something-radiobuttons"]=== undefined || s.model["something-radiobuttons"] === "radioOne");
                },
                templateOptions: {
                    label: 'tom',
                    required: true,
                    datepickerOptions: {
                        format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                    }
                }
```

The first click, shows correct date in input field but shows todays date grayed in. in the second image i flip it to the input field-date and its blue. Second time I click the datepicker it immediatly goes to the blue date.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the model inside $scope.apply

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.model.to = fromDate;
});
```

Comment: this gives me "[object Object]" in the input text field, and when i click the datepicker it still shows todays date.

Comment: what is the value of JSON.stringify(s.model.to) after you set the date and it displays correctly?

Comment: user19, okay so i put a 'console.log($scope.model.to);' in the $scope.datepicker.open function and it shows the correct date six months ahead both times, even though the datepicker first opens up at todays date and after I open it the second time it shows the correct date.

Comment: I added some images.

Comment: no, I am reading about it right now. Where do u suggest using it?

Comment: @teachMe I changed my original answer as I realized this was wrong, try using $scope.apply(), it should force an update.

Comment: I tried wrapping the passing of the value to the model.to and it didnt do any difference. I tried it in the controller in customFormType.js and then i tried it in the radiobutton-onChange event. No dice.

Comment: Can you please set up a Plunker with the relevant code? I created a demo based on the samples from the site, but cannot reproduce your issue.